# ArcGIS Android HelloWorld MapView InflateException

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I'm new to ArcGIS Android i'm trying HelloWord app but its giving me exception.. I checked libraries in project build path, 
Android Tools> Fix Project Properties, 
ArcGIS Tools> Fix Project Properties

This code worked for me in Real device but exception in Emulator.. I did every thing giving [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/05/02/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-v1-1-supports-android-emulator/)..

i did all these but still same error plz help me to fix it...

Here is stack trace..

`07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hello/com.hello.HellowordActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.esri.android.map.MapView
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.esri.android.map.MapView
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.hello.HellowordActivity.onCreate(HellowordActivity.java:18)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     ... 11 more
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     ... 22 more
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.esri.android.map.MapView.a(Unknown Source)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.esri.android.map.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     ... 25 more
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load runtimecore_java: findLibrary returned null
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.esri.core.internal.util.e$1.initialize(Unknown Source)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.esri.android.io.a.a(Unknown Source)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
07-15 16:44:36.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     ... 27 more`

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to reproduce your issue on Mac or Win. But here are some things to confirm to ensure your settings are correct:

SDK Manager

1. Ensure **ARM EABI v7a System Image** is installed for the SDK you are targeting. Remember you must use Android 4.0.3 (API 15) or higher.

AVD Emulator

1. Choose a device based on Android 4.0.3 or higher.
2. Choose **ARM (armeabi-v7a)** for CPU/ABI.
3. Select **Use Host Emulation** in the Emulation Options.

Project Settings

1. Right click your project and select **Properties**.
2. Select **Java Build Path > Order and Export** tab
3. Make sure **ArcGIS for Android 10.1.1** is selected.

Run your project as Android Project on the Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have issues with the ArcGIS Runtime for Android. Could you provide information as to whether you have it installed and configured correctly. If not please use this link (http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.all) to download and configure the ArcGIS runtime for Android (I have mine installed for eclipse) and retry with the HelloWorld sample and several of the great many samples the good folks at ESRI have provided. Let me know how it turns out. Would love to help further.

P.S.: you might need to register a global account with esri in order to download. It's free just sign up

Comment: I'm Using Eclipse Indigo SR2, JDK 1.7, ADT Ver22, ArcGIS for Android v10.1.1-u1

Comment: It appears it cannot see the mapView class. Check the AndroidManifest.xml file to make sure the any changes you might have made are correctly updated. Also try checking the versions of the ADT on the device and the emulator are the correct versions for the project. The emulator might not have the needed version of the API and finally after you do all the above, clean your project before you run it again.